# Is it possible to put myBatis (iBatis) xml mappers outside the project?

Tags: ibatis

According to the user guide i am able to use file path instead of 
resource:

```
// Using classpath relative resources
<mappers>
    <mapper resource="org/mybatis/builder/AuthorMapper.xml"/>
</mappers>

// Using url fully qualified paths
<mappers>
    <mapper url="file:///var/sqlmaps/AuthorMapper.xml"/>
</mappers>
```

in my project I'm trying to put my mapper xml "outside" the project 
and i'm doing this:

```
<mapper url="file://D:/Mappers/ComponentMapper1.xml" />
```

The output of my log4j console:
`Error building SqlSession. 
The error may exist in file://D:/Mappers/ComponentMapper1.xml 
Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing 
SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.net.UnknownHostException: D` 


Is it bug or it's me doing something wrong?

Comment: I've updated ibatis to the newest version, added thirth slash: <mapper url="file:///D:/Mappers/ComponentMapper1.xml" /> and it works just fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need an additional forward slash before the drive letter.

Answer (score 0):

Sql Map Config looks for mapping files relatively to the classpath, so just try adding your *ComponentMapper1.xml* somewhere to the classpath.

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;D:/Mappers/

...

<mapper resource="ComponentMapper1.xml" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You must use

```
<mapper url="file:///usr/local/ComponentMapper1.xml" />
```

Where `file:///usr/local/ComponentMapper1.xml`is the path to your XML File, instead of the resource if you want use mappers outside resource dir.